# In app Purchase : App store receipt validation on device: How to handle the condition if user changes the device date to past

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My app has a functionality of auto-renewable subscription. To validate the subscription, I'm trying to validate app store receipt locally on device, For now i'm checking the expiration date of receipt with device's current date. But this condition may fail if user changes the device date to past.

How can i handle this condition?

Any help much appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Validate on a server where you can trust the time

Answer (score 0):

The correct way and the securest would be to use a server as Paulw11 already wrote. Nevertheless, there are ways of identifying users who eventually turned their device time back, but personally, I wouldn't use them in production to restrict access to features or content, because they're unreliable and I would rather have someone who uses my service for free than possibly several whom I wrongly exclude.
I have used the following approaches only to get a feeling on how many users actually tried to get access by turning their device time back and it turned out, that the number was that small, that I decided that it was not worth investing more time on that.

Enough waffling, here are my approaches:

1) Every time you do the local receipt validation you could save the current time to the user defaults and compare the last saved value with the current device time.

2) Pull the current time from some clock api from the internet (for example http://worldclockapi.com/)